How to use Mongoid field type Set?
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :bars, type: Set
end

f = Foo.new
f.add_to_set(bars: 1)
f.bars
=> nil
f.attributes['bars']
=> [1]

Is there any better way to access f.bars?
Mongoid 9.0.0

I don't think Mongo actually knows how to deserialize Set. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/reference/fields/#custom-field-types

It's a valid field: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/reference/fields/#field-types

Ah, you're right.

Your code isn't actually reproducable.
irb(main):007:0> f = Foo.new
irb(main):008:0> f.add_to_set(bars: 1)
=> #<Foo _id: 66dc4cc6fbdbbf68304b94bd, bars: [1]>
irb(main):009:0> f.bars
=> #<Set: {1}>
irb(main):010:0> f.read_attribute(:bars)
=> #<Set: {1}>
irb(main):011:0> f[:bars]
=> #<Set: {1}>
irb(main):012:0> f.attributes
=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('66dc4cc6fbdbbf68304b94bd'), "bars"=>[1]}
irb(main):013:0> Mongoid::VERSION
=> "9.0.0"

The attributes method returns the raw attributes as they are serialized so getting an array instead of a set should be expected.
Just like with ActiveRecord you can access attributes through the getter method, the :[] method or read_attribute.

You're right. I was using the field name complete in a model with other code. I guess there was a naming or other conflict.
